# SugarCRM: Deprecated SOAP API calls?

Tags: api, soap, sugarcrm

Is it true that most of the web methods available in SugarCRM's SOAP API are now deprecated and replaced by set_entry() and get_entry() ?

For example, if I want to create a new lead should I use create_lead() or should I stick to set_entry() on "Leads" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be correct. I use get_module_fields($session_id, 'Contacts') to get the fields for whatever module I am creating or updating. Replace Contacts with whatever module you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, version 5.2 has the SugarCRM SOAP v1 api and version 5.5 has version1 api and a version 2 api.

You just have to use different urls to access the api that you want in 5.5.